# Game doesn't show up in the App List

Tags: apps

I installed a game (March of Empires), was working fine, but after an update it disappeared. Store shows the game as 'Installed' and there seems to be no way to un-install it.

1. It doesn't show up in the App List.
2. It doesn't show up in the Storage Sense.
3. Microsoft app called 'Files' which is kind of File Explorer does show its folder but there I don't get an option to make any kind of changes such as un-install an app or delete a folder.**

My Phone: **Microsoft Lumia 640 LTE; Windows Phone 8.1 Update 2**

I will highly appreciate your help, anyone who knows how to un-install this game or delete it without 'Hard Reset', please let me know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise that you try a soft reset before sacrificing your data and time in doing a hard reset.
This method will not remove anything at all from your phone and is completely safe to attempt in any problem situation.

Whilst your phone is on:
**Press and hold the <kbd>Volume Down</kbd> and <kbd>Power</kbd> buttons at the same time until you feel a vibration (about 10–15 seconds). Ignore the "slide down to power off" screen.**

Soft resetting a phone usually resolve application problems.

However, if after a soft reset, the application still does not show on the application list, I advise you go through the **Store**, click the ellipsis (3 dots) and click Downloads. Under there, swipe your finger to the left/right to reveal the Applications Installation History.
If the said game does not show on the application history, then I bet it won't be installed in your phone. So you can go ahead and search for it, and try reinstalling it again.
But, if it says its installed: Still in the store and under the application's profile, click on the "View" button, and it will reveal the application in the application list on the phone.

Also, you can go and try checking for the game from under the "Games" Application.

After you have tried everything I have specified, and you still cannot find it, but from the Store and application installation history it shows that it is installed in the phone, then you can go ahead and do a [Hard Reset](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mobiledevices/wiki/mdlumia-mdsettings/how-to-soft-and-hard-reset-your-windows-phone/4ec36474-c21e-4aec-ad1b-30f3afaf824d).

Answer (score 0):

As Windows Phone mechanism, you will not find any folder for any application you have by default or you install on SD Card or phone memory.

So Definitely, you will not find folder to delete in order to delete the app. So you have only option to do so.

*I had the same issue with the app "UC Browser",*
I got it resolved by resetting the phone from ***Settings > about > reset***.

> Note : It will erase all your data in Phone memory and all apps on Phone and SD Card.

Comment: Advising a factory reset is not a good thing to do at all, but advising without indicating that this will erase all the data on the phone is even a worse thing to do. This should be the last step always.